# Force A Reply WPA/WPA2

Tags: wireless, wpa2, data-link-layer

I am working on an open source project, and am currently stumped.

Let’s say I have a client connect to a wireless WPA network I am not authenticated to the wireless network I just have a wireless card in monitor mode. Is there a way Is there something I can send the client that will cause them to send something in response? There response doesn’t need to be to me as a destination I just want to be able to do something that forces the client to send some traffic as a response. I know deauth packets are one possible solution but I was looking for other suggestions.